# GIT: Output repository changes to a file, and then apply to an another repo

Tags: git

How to push to a repo to which I have no network connection? I thought there may be a way to output all changes to a file, copy it to USB, and then apply the changes to another repo, which resides in a different computer.

Answer (score 3):

The [git format-patch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) command will produce a series of patches, one file per commit.  You can then apply these to another repository using the [git am](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) command.

This is effectively the workflow used for developing the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use patches.

```
git format-patch -1 <commit SHA1 id>
```

It should create a .patch file with the contents of that specific commit. If you want that commit plus the *`n`* commits preceeding it, replace `-1` for the number of commits (-2, -3 etc.).

Then, in the peer use `git apply` to import that commit's .patch file to the repository.